# cakephp 3.0 - Saving unique asscociations

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, orm, associations

One of the reasons using ORM is - in my opinion - to prevent duplicate records in a table. To reach this it is possible to create foreign keys to link multiple tables together.

My problem is as follows:

Table 'addresses':

```
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| country_id    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city_id       | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| street_id     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| zip_id        | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| street_number | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table 'countries':

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(45) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

(same logic to the other tables)

When I try to save an entry with a country-name which already exist I'll get an mysql unique error. This is clear and absolutely okay. Everything works as intended.

The question is: What is the best practice to save entities with (unique) associations which already exists and how is it possible to get the id (foreign key) of the existing (e.g. country.id) to link it in the addresses table?

Is there any cake-magic which fits for my case?

Thanks in advance,

Phil

Comment: _What is the best practice to save entities with (unique) associations which already exist_? What entities? What unique associations? Please clarify your question (for instance, show sample data that you have and are trying to save.) _How is it possible to get the id (foreign key) of the existing (e.g. country.id) to link it in the addresses table?_ This seems to be a basic/ rudimentary use of the **find** method on the related model. Once again, using sample data as an example of the problem you are trying to solve will help others provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Surely you're not going to ever be creating a country when creating an address - you'd be using a select (or similar) and specifying the address.country_id only. The way you've phrased the question you're doing something weird - but there's no code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first develop a logical relationship model on paper by hand and think more about the possible data combinations and relations before you dive into practice with a framework like CakePHP.

It's ok to separate data in multiple tables to avoid double entries - but only if it makes sense. Unfortunately it doesn't make sense for all the fields in your address example and your relations also seem to be not logical.

Also it's difficult to recommend you something without knowing what you are planning to do or what kind of data (addresses) you are talking about. Is it a private address book with a few ~100 entries or is it a big sized application with thousand or millions of addresses form a whole country or even multiple countries...

Example 1: Cities and zip codes

- A `city` can possibly have **multiple** `zip codes` (in some countries) and a single `zip code` **belongs to** one `city` (at least within one country).
- An `address` **has one** `zip code` and a single `zip code` can be linked to **many** `addresses`.
- As you have this relations you don't need to connect the `addresses` table to the `cities` table as you get the `city` name via the `zip code`. Your connection line is: `Address` **has one** `zip code` that **belongs to one** `city`.

Example 2: Street names

- A `street name` can be used in **multiple** `cities` and a `city` can have **multiple** `streets`. This sounds like a **many to many** connection.
- But also keep in mind that street names may be altered (new orthography, renamed after a special event or because of other special local circumstances). This won't happen often but it may occur. So if you update a street name within the many-to-many relation the street name is changed for all linked cities. This is a point where it might be relevant what kind of addresses you are talking about and it you might need to think about a way how to manage this kind of changes.

Example 3: Street numbers

- I personally would not use a separate table for street numbers as they are often very short and can also be "special", e.g. "5", "632 b", "36826 3rd floor" or whatever.
- (I'm not quite sure with this, but I think there is not a big difference according to the request time or database size if you save the street number directy with the address, as a foreign key might have a similar length)

Now to your main question at the end:

There is no ready-to-use "magic" in CakePHP to handle this. First you should fix your table relations, than you can work with some tools (behaviours) provided by CakePHP, but for this kind of records you will have to code own logic as well.

If you add a new adress you need to

- **find** lists of related tables, **set** them to the view templates and use them there with the **form helper** to create select lists (eg dropdown)
- add links in the add/edit-address-view to create new cities/zips/whatever

And for a userfriendly input form you will probably have to use some javascript/Ajax as well to change options in select-dropdowns according to other selected values, eg show only zip codes available for a preselected city or add a new street name on the fly...

This answer is long to read but only filled with some hints. Please note that your question is too broad to be answered here in detail. For the next question please be more specific to a coding related problem, add code examples and also view the tips at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), thank you.